# Is there a reason null can be an element of HashSet in Java?

Tags: java, hashset

A HashSet is essentially used to do constant time lookups for items. Why would there be a need to look up for a null item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would there be a need to look up for a null item?

Because `null` could well be a valid value for an item ... according to the program design that the programmer has developed!!

(IMO, that is probably a bad idea in most cases, but it is not really up to you and me to make that call.)

Once you accept that the programmer could have a valid use-case for a `null` item, then it makes sense for `HashSet` to deal with `null` so that the programmer doesn't need to treat a `null` as a special case when putting it into a set.

---

When designing an API, there is a tension between how the API designer thinks that an API should be used and how the user of the API thinks it should be used.  It is a bad idea for the API designer to try to impose their view too strongly, especially when the justification is debatable.

There can also be a tension between generality and efficiency.  In this case, we would need to examine the actual runtime cost of allowing `null` items.  On the face of it, there needs to be an extra test to see if an item is `null`.  However, a deeper analysis of the code may well reveal that the alternative version has an *implicit* `null` test under the hood ... to deal with the case where a `NullPointerException` needs to be thrown.